# How to solve the problem: can't assign to literal (Python)?

Tags: python, list, numpy-ndarray

For this following code I get the error: can't assign to literal

```
for i in range(len(stepData)):
    stepDataLeft = stepData.to_numpy()[i, 0:5]
    stepDataRight = stepData.to_numpy()[i, 5:10]
    dataF = pd.DataFrame({'stepDataLeft': stepDataLeft, 'stepDataRight': stepDataRight}, index=['Stride Length Mean', 'Stand Duration Mean', 'Swing Duration Mean', 'Douple Support Time Mean', 'Relation Swing Stand Mean'])
    dataF = ['Symmetry Ratio Row']=resultsPerRowRatio.append(np.where(dataF['stepDataLeft'] < dataF['stepDataRight'],sv.symmetryRatio(dataF['stepDataLeft'],dataF['stepDataRight']), sv.symmetryRatio(df['stepDataRight'],df['stepDataLeft'])))
print(str(dataF))
```

-

```
import numpy as np

def symmetryRatio(L, R):
    result = L/R
    return result
```

Could someone explain me what's the problem and how I can solve it, please?

**EDIT 1**
[image]

**EDIT 2**

After my correction I get this error:

[image]

Comment: please specify the error in breif or paste it along with your question

Comment: Oh yes. You're right. Thank you. But then I get this error: KeyError: 'stepDataRight' and I don't know what that means and how to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

Write this instead:

```
dataF['Symmetry Ratio Row'] = ...
```

Comment: Oh yes. You're right. 
But then I get this error: KeyError: 'stepDataRight'

Comment: @hugmath that means your dataframe has no such column. Perhaps you meant to create columns in the first two lines, or you meant to use the variable name in the last line?

Comment: I want three column names: StepDataLeft, StepDataRight and SymmetryRatioRow

Comment: @hugmath then the first line should be `dataF['stepDataLeft']=...`